# Unity Licensing

Tags: unity, android, ios, licensing

I'm sorry if this gets asked a lot but google gives up answers from back in 2008 and all sorts so  could somebody please clear up a couple of questions for me please.

I want to make 2D games in Unity, I've made my first one following a tutorial online with Unity free version and I don't see that I will really need any more advanced features than what's available in there.

However, I do want to release to both Android and iOS. When I finished making the game it already lets me build to an APK which I can run on my phone and tablet so my question is really do I need the pro licenses?

Also I'm considering at some point in the future I may want to include paid adverts in my game, can this still be done with free versions?

Comment: Unity 5 gives you all engine features for free. There's nothing you shouldn't be able to do with it that you can do with the paid version. Unity 5 does not require separate licenses for those mobile platforms. Yes, you can have ads in your game with the free version. The biggest 'problem' you may have with the free version is that it must include a "Unity personal edition" splash screen.

Comment: About your needs of the pro version: you're the only one in position to determine if you'll need the features or not. And about the licensing: how about reading the license?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the details of a software license, best answered by that software license or its writers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the pro license to release games for any platform. You just have to upgrade if you made more than 100k in funding or revenue.

I believe paid advertisements can be done with the free version.

https://unity3d.com/unity/faq

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. For arguments sake, lets say I did want to use the pro license, do I have to then buy iOS and Android pro too?If not, what are they actually for?

Comment: @WinterSoldier5 yes, you would.